# Составить алгоритм

Tags: php, html

Всем привет.

Есть сайт http://moneyback.ru/. Там регистрируешься, и чтобы получить бонус, нужно перейти в любой из магазинов и сделать оплату, после чего тебе начислится бонус.

Подскажите, как здесь орагнизован алгоритм? Хочу создать у себя такой же сервис в городе Алматы.

Вот что получилось наработать.

1. После перехода создается Get параметр примерно вот такого типа: "?actionpay=d41d9ff0-93f4-63ef-f58f-014a208c214c.47553"
2. Я так понимаю, чтобы партнерская ссылка сохранилась, ее записывать в Куки, после чего ты спокойно можешь гулять по их сайту.
3. Вопрос: после того как я нажимаю Купить, как партнер узнает, что клиент пришел от меня? Нужно на его стороне писать код: взять такую-то куки и записать в базу данных, от кого он пришел.
4. После того как человек оплатил товар, партнер должен зайти в личный кабинет у меня на сайте и провести покупку?

Что-то я тут написал бредового или нет? Подскажите ваше видение этого проекта, а точнее алгоритм?

Comment: А если я зарегился на http://moneyback.ru/.  А на сайт магаза зашел не через их сайт - то все, бонусов не будет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте пройдем по Вашим пунктам:

1. У Вас на сайте будет ссылка на какой-то магазин, в котором Ваш клиент должен совершить покупку. И для этого вы формируете либо GET-ссылку с необходимым параметром`:"?actionpay=d41d9ff0-93f4-63ef-f58f-014a208c214c.47553"`
2. Да, вы совершенно правы - записывается необходимая кука. С помощью данной куки можно определить, с какого сайта был переход.
3. Во время покупки партнер считывает куку и записывает в необходимое поле, "от кого пришел клиент".
4. Партнер к Вам на сайт не должен заходить. Он просто может использовать ваше API. После обращения которого вы запишите необходимые данные в базу. И у пользователя, который вернется к Вам, на сайте уже будет скидка или бонусы какие-то.

**UPD!**

У нас есть сайт [1] и сайт [2]. Для получение бонуса на сайте [1] пользователь должен совершить покупку на сате [2].

У Вас, получается, есть зарегистрированный клиент на сайте [1].

Я бы формировал GET запрос следующим образом:

```
?urlSite={Имя домена с которого пришел клиент}&user={Логин_зарегистрированого_пользователя}
```

Ну, только обязательно эти вещи необходимо шифровать. В любом случае данные, отправленные GET запросом, можно перехватить.
Поэтому такие вещи лучше передавать POST-ом.

В вашем случае данные можно не шифровать, ничего секретного в Ваших передаваемых данных нету.

Далее пользователь переходит на сайт [2]. Сайт обрабатывает пришедший GET запрос и записывает в куку данные: urlSite и user.
Потом пользователь гуляет по сайту, выбирает товар. Выключает комп. Думает месяц над покупкой товара и потом совершает покупку.
И тут считывается кука, которая была записана месяц назад. 
И сайт [2] определяет логин клиента и urlSite, с которого пришел данный клиент.

А далее все просто, например, вызывается API:

`$apiPayPartner->Success(urlSite, user, "и например_номер_заказа")`

Сюда можно запихнуть что угодно, например, информацию о приобретенном товаре, его цену и т.д.

И после вызова API на сайте [1] срабатывает функция `Success()`, в которой приходят необходимые Вам данные.
И далее вы их сохраняете в БД. 
И теперь пользователь, зайдя на сайт, увидит свой обещанный бонус. :)

И используя такой алгоритм, можно подключать сколько угодно сайтов.

**UPD 2.**

По поводу того, как это все описать клиенту. То для этих целей создается документ, в котором описаны все эти мелочи. И указывается на него ссылка, и, как правило, клиенты их не читают. А если и прочитают, то еще лучше. :)

Comment: А какое API должно быть? Точнее как оно будет выглядить, какой доступ будет у партнера?

Comment: Если после первого пункта юзер почистил куки - то все, бонуса нету?

Comment: Да, если Юзер почистит куки - то все пропадет. Или если воспользуется другим браузером.

duddeniska, лучше всего использовать REST API. Можете почитать про него в интернете.

Comment: тогда получается какой то "жидковатый" алгоритм. Причем на сайте о том что нельзя так поступать НИЧЕГО не говориться. Так же не говорится что бонус будет начислен только при переходе в интернет магазин с сайта.

Comment: Ну почему жидкий? Вы много знаете юзеров, которые чистят постоянно куки?

Comment: Хорошо, как вы тогда идентифицируете пользователя, который совершил покупку на сайте партнера? 
Такие вещи всегда работают по кукам. Здесь не берется в расчет, что пользователь будет чистить куки или менять браузер.

Comment: Можно, конечно, делать не через куки, а например, после покупки выдавать пользователю какой-нибудь ключ. И он после покупки заходит на Ваш сайт и вводит этот ключ. А вы уже проверяете, есть ли такой ключ. Если есть, то даете ему скидку и помечаете этот ключ как использованный.

Comment: Я сейчас добавлю UPD. То, как бы я это все сделал. Обождите минут 10.

Comment: ПО поводу жидкий. Вы плохо знаете людей, который ко всему в данном случае выступают клиентами. Как только клиент услышал о всяких плюшках в его сторону - о считает что они у него в кармане. И не дай бог клиент ее не получит по какой либо причине - будет такой ОР стоять. И другой момент - людям тогда нада четко описывать механизм возврата денег, и указать на те моменты про которые я описал выше - по которым он может лишиться возврата денег.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю другой способ реализации.

1. Юзер регится на сайте возврата денег (далее СВД).
2. На СВД ему присваивается некий уникальный ключ типа d41d9ff0-93f4-63ef-f58f-014a208c214c.47553. И юзеру говрится о том, что это типа номер его виртуальной карты.
3. Далее при совершении покупки на сайтах партнерах юзер вводит этот номер виртуальной карты.Тут, кстати, можно сделать так: указать номер карты при регистрации.
4. На сайте партнера по API на СВД отсылается ключ, и юзеру начисляют возврат денег.

Единственное, что нужно определить понятие "совершение покупки", а точнее когда этот момент настает, так как, по Закону о защите прав потребителей, при интернет-покупке у клиента есть возможность вернуть товар после его получения без объяснения причины от 7 до 90 дней.